# A simple http GET request doesn't hit the express js api

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have a simple node/express js api that receives request from another app.The request is this `GET /api/users?data=5`. Whenever i hardcode data with 5 like above, it does hit `/api/users` route.But whenever i send the request with dynamic data like `GET /api/users?data=id` where id = 5, it DOESN'T hit `/api/users` route, But in the server logs i do see the request did hit with url `/users?data=5`.I am not sure whats wrong but i am suspecting maybe i didnt define the routes correctly.Any help will be appreciated.Sorry I am new to Node js. Thank you.Here is my code

```
 var app = express();
 var router = express.Router();
 router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(); 
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home');

});
 app.use('/api', router);
 router.route('/users')

   .get (function(req, res) {
    var data = req.query.data;
    });
```

Comment: Try moving your `app.use('/api', router);` to the bottom of your code, after your `router.route('users')` stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but  that didn't work.

Comment: Can you post how you do your client request? are you hitting browser or using client?

Comment: Its Client `GET /api/users?data=id HTTP/1.1`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out , in the request `GET /api/users?data=id HTTP/1.` id was not properly formated ,hence the request was hitting the server but not application layer.

**UPDATE**
In short the app that make Http GET request is written in arduino (which translates it to C).I was reading the ID from the device memory which is saved as char array.So i thought i had converted the char array to string but in reality was still chars, and i put this variable in the url for Get request that is why it was complaining.

Comment: If you post your incorrect formatting and the correct one it might be beneficial to others.